# Incremental migration from VSS 2005 to Git

Tags: git, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have a relatively big VSS 2005 database that I want to migrate to Git.

It's not definitive migration just yet.

I need to perform some tests on the migration to see if everything will be there.

Meanwhile, my coworkers will still keep using VSS 2005.
Nothing fancy on the VSS use, no branches or merges. Just checkouts and checkins. Maybe some new files added.

Is it possible to migrate from on this condition?
Do you have any idea on what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving incremental project folders to Git as commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789031/moving-incremental-project-folders-to-git-as-commits)