# Moving incremental project folders to Git as commits

Tags: git

I have an archaic source code management system at the moment that I'd like to move to Git. I have multiple copies of the same project folder; each time I complete a release/new feature I copy the latest folder, increment the name and start working on that. It's bad, but I've been the only developer so it works. I'd like to move the project over to Git with each folder being an individual commit, but have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the only way I can think to do this - it may take a bit of time...

First, initialize a git directory. You do this by (assuming unix/mac os) changing to the desired directory (`cd <dir_path>`) and running `git init` from the terminal. Here is a [reference](http://gitref.org/creating/).

Next copy all the contents of the version #1 folder to the git directory. Once you have done this run `git .add` from the terminal (this should stage everything in the git directory for a commit). Now you are ready to commit your code: `git commit -m 'ver 1.0 commit message'`.

Next delete all the contents (except the `.git` folder!) from your git directory and then copy in all the contents of the version #2 folder. Then run your add and commit commands again. Repeat until you are on your current version.

Once you have done this I recommend setting up some sort of remote repository to push your project to. [GitHub](https://github.com/) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) are both really good!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it will work. I just would like to add that this operations could be easily automated using some scripting language.

Comment: I agree - if there are more than probably like 5-10 versions depending on how proficient you are in the scripting language!

Comment: May be easier to just move the .git folder than clearing out the working directory each time

Comment: Glad to hear! Good luck.